# Determining for what user was a session invalidated

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, invalidation

Using JBoss 5.1.0 GA. In the web.xml of my application I`m defining such session-invalidation timeout :

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

How could I find out for which user was the session invalidated ?

I tried intercepting the sessionDestroyed event with a HttpSessionListener and getting the request by using

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
```

but the principal is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store user name in session when it gets created for that user after logging into the application.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("USER_NAME", "xyz");
```

Get the user before invalidating the session.

```
session.getAttribute("USER_NAME");
```